# How to change outlier point symbol in Python matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, shapes, outliers

I am trying to change the usual Boxplot outlier shape (the jitter above the boxes) which is a circle by default to a diamond. I am using the following code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

box = plt.boxplot([x1, x2], labels = ["Var1_Name",  
"Var2_Name"], notch=True, patch_artist=True)
```

Is there a way to make this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the properties of the fliers via [`flierprops`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

box = plt.boxplot([np.random.randn(200), np.random.randn(200)], labels=["Var1_Name", "Var2_Name"],
                  notch=True, patch_artist=True,
                  flierprops={'marker': 'o', 'markersize': 10, 'markerfacecolor': 'fuchsia'})
```

[image: example plot]

To only change the symbol, you can leave out `flierprops=` and just use `sym='*'`. If, on the contrary, you need more control or need their exact positions, the fliers are also returned by `box = plt.boxplot(...)` as `box['fliers']`.